# Is there any way to save a dirty canvas?

Tags: image, html, video, canvas

I am making screenshots of videos with HTML5 canvas, the video is hosted elsewhere, everything works except toDataURL() because the canvas is dirty.  So, I am wondering, is there any way I can save this canvas image on the computer?

I assume the answer is no but hoping for some hack to get this done, well any idea apart from downloading the video to my server and serving it from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No."

The longer answer might be yes.

Maybe your server can download the video and host it, then play it from your same domain?

If you control the server that is hosting the video you could [enable cors](http://enable-cors.org/).

(Or you could combine the two and have the video uploaded to a cors-enabled site that is not your own.)

Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

What about, I haven't tried it yet, if you redraw the original canvas on another canvas which you then save to an image. (and use css or position the canvases over each other to "hide" the second canvas).

Will the second canvas be dirty?

([thinking about a technique like thisone](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/))

Answer (score 0):

I tried the copying of the canvas but this just returned the same dirty canvas error.

In the end to get this work I implemented a small service that would extract remote sources (videos) and make them look as though they were local i.e.  by reading the source server side and writing out to my HTML/JS page. Once this was done it all worked fine.

I used Python / Flask to do this, here is the snippet. Not perfect in regards to handle partial content requests but should get someone going.

To use it I access my videos using: /remote?url=

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import make_response, request, current_app, Flask, url_for, render_template, Response
from functools import update_wrapper
import requests
import logging
import json
from werkzeug.datastructures import Headers
import httplib
import os
import subprocess
import base64
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

app = Flask(__name__)


logging.basicConfig() 
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None,
                max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True,
                automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator

def stream_remote(url, headers=None):
    logging.debug(headers) 
    range = headers["Range"]
    logging.debug(range)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"range":range})
    logging.debug(r.headers)
    for block in r.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
            break
        yield block


@app.route('/remote/')
def get_remote():
    # Gets a remote file to make it look like it is local for CORS purposes
    url = request.args.get("url", None)
    resp_headers = Headers()
    resp_headers.add('Accept-Ranges','bytes')

    if url is None:
        return "Error. No URL provided"
    else:
        headers = request.headers
        logging.debug(headers)
        return Response(stream_remote(url, headers),mimetype='video/mp4',headers=resp_headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=9001)
```