# How to read loaded image into a blob?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert an image object to a binary blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375333/how-to-convert-an-image-object-to-a-binary-blob)

I am facing same-origin policy restrictions when loading remote images. However DOM 0 Image object can be used to load a remote resource (this is essentially the same as creating an `<img />` tag).

```
var fr = new FileReader(),
    img = new Image();

img.src = 'http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/6cf25568491a11e2af8422000a9e28e9_7.jpg';

img.onload = function () {
    // how to get this image as a Blob object?
};
```

Is there a way to read this resource into a Blob/arraybuffer object? This is not a duplicate of [How to convert an image object to a binary blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375333/how-to-convert-an-image-object-to-a-binary-blob) as the latter does not rise with same-origin issues.

Comment: You can put the image on a canvas, then read the canvas as a blob.  I think.  I'm not sure how to use canvas, but I think you can do that.

Comment: That actually sounds plausible! Will try it and post an update if it works.

Comment: Go for it.  Good luck! :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat just saw your comment. I have the same answer but unfortunately it doesn't work. In the canvas element you have same-origin restriction too, so you cant export the canvas to binary/data url if you've drawn remote image over it...

Comment: @MinkoGechev: Darn.  Oh well, that was all I could think of.

Comment: You could use a server-side language, like PHP to proxy the image, so that it's "local".

Comment: @RocketHazmat proxy is not an option as the purpose of the script is exactly to reduce the server-side bandwidth.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas: I think you may be out of options then.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519386/is-there-any-way-to-save-a-dirty-canvas

Comment: Also related (with a potential solution using CORS): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672643/html5-canvas-getimagedata-and-same-origin-policy

Comment: @apsillers as I have mentioned before, this scenario is dealing with the case where there is no control over the remote content.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it can be accomplished without much pain...

You just need one more HTML5 element. When using `canvas` you can draw the remote image on it. After that getting the image dataUrl is quite easy, you have such function from the canvas's API. The next step is to use FileReader's `readAsDataURL` method.

I haven't tried it but theoretically it should work.

- Edit: It won't work. If the image is from different origin you can't use canvas's `toDataURL` method. So I don't think there's any solution without server-side.

Comment: Just to prove that this doesn't work, http://jsbin.com/apabor/1/edit for those (like me) who want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I guess you need node, php or something else in server-side...

Comment: @MinkoGechev Are there any news on this topic meanwhile?

Comment: Nope, you need server side because of cross-origin restrictions.