# How to force/allow the user to download multiple files? (client side)

Tags: javascript, html, flash

The input is a variable number of URLs (remote), all linking image resource. It is desired to allow user to allow to download all of these URLs in one batch. Since we are talking about 1000-2000 image resources, asking user to click "Save As..." for every URL is not feasible.

My original attempt was to download all the images into a blob ([How to read loaded image into a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937494/how-to-read-loaded-image-into-a-blob), did not work because of the same-origin policy), archive the file and allow the user to download it (all of this client side).

I was wondering what are possible alternative solutions? Whatever the solution is, it must not involve downloading the remote resources to the server at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Although it shouldn’t be possible, I managed to do this in Chrome with some sorcery. First you need to set the `download` attrbute to all your links f.ex:

```
<a href="http://example.com/image1.jpg" download>download</a>
<a href="http://example.com/image2.jpg" download>download</a>
```

Then create a synthetic click function:

```
function makeClick(element) {
    var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true,
        element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
        false, false, false, 1, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}​
```

Then just loop through your links and call it:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<links.length; i++) {
    makeClick(links[i]);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/37pFC/

In Chrome you will get a warning saying something like "This site wants you to download multiple files. Allow?" but this might be manageable.

**Disclaimer:** I havent tried in other browsers, and I don’t think it’s very cross-browser friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't think about anything better but to prepare an archive on the server side, based on user's preference, and then have the user download the package.

I guess you could have the user install a browser extension that would allow a bit more control over binary data and the local filesystem, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.